# How to find out index in plotly in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly

On this web-site https://plotly.com/r/trisurf/ there are lots of 3D figurs. For example

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 0),
  y = c(0, 0, 1, 2),
  z = c(0, 2, 0, 1),
  i = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
  j = c(1, 2, 3, 2),
  k = c(2, 3, 1, 3),
  facecolor = toRGB(viridisLite::viridis(4))
)

fig
```

[image]

I don't understand how find out this:

```
i = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
      j = c(1, 2, 3, 2),
      k = c(2, 3, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8960/what-are-the-i-j-k-components-of-a-3d-mesh-on-plot-ly-online) help?

Comment: [Here](https://plotly-r.com/) is a book.

Answer (score 1):

The `x`, `y` and `z` vectors:

```
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 0),
  y = c(0, 0, 1, 2),
  z = c(0, 2, 0, 1),
```

represent four points `(0,0,0)`, `(1,0,2)`, `(2,1,0)`, `(0,2,1)`. They are indexed by 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively.

The `i`, `j`, `k` vectors:

```
i = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
j = c(1, 2, 3, 2),
k = c(2, 3, 1, 3)
```

represent four triangles. The first one is represented by `(0,1,2)`. This means the vertices of the corresponding triangle are the points indexed by 0, 1, 2. The second one, `(0,2,3)`, is the triangle whose vertices are the points indexed by 0, 2, 3. Etc.